# Rotating CCSprite thats an equilateral triangle

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, rotation, geometry, ccsprite

I have an CCSprite thats an equilateral triangle. I want to rotate the triangle in 60 degree increments holding its position.

The sprite is 126x110 (not square) setting the sprites rotation property in 60 degree increments changes the position of the sprite. How can i keep the sprite appear stationary at each rotation?

A bit more about this the center of the rectangle IS NOT the center of the sprite. So there is some adjustment needed when the rotation is needed to keep the center of the triangle appearing centered.

I think i came up with a long answer that needs to be approved..

```
    // collect points.
    self.point1 = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.tile.boundingBox)/2, 0);
    self.point2 = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.tile.boundingBox), CGRectGetHeight(self.tile.boundingBox));
    self.point3 = CGPointMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(self.tile.boundingBox));

    // calculcate the mid point.
    float midPointX = floor((self.point1.x + self.point2.x + self.point3.x)/3.0);
    float midPointY = floor((self.point1.y + self.point2.y + self.point3.y)/3.0);

   // stash the center of the triangle
    self.triangleCenter = CGPointMake(midPointX, midPointY);
```

Then figure out new location  of the center point based on rotation.. And animate there. (Sorry about hard coded center of the screen this was a rough test).

```
-(void) rotateToAngleAboutCenter:(float)angle {

        // stash old values.
        CGPoint oldPosition = self.tile.position;
        float oldRotation = self.tile.rotation;

        // reset the rotation
       self.tile.rotation = 0;

       // this is hard coded here currently the center of the screen.
       self.tile.position =  ccp(512, 384);

       // figure out where our center point will be when we are rotated about the center.
       CGPoint point = ccpRotateByAngle(self.triangleCenter, [self.tile anchorPointInPoints],-CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle));

      // convert the ppoint to local space.
      point = [self.tile convertToWorldSpace:point];

      point = [self convertToNodeSpace:point];

      // reset the rotation and position.
      self.tile.rotation = oldRotation;
      self.tile.position = oldPosition;

      // animate to new rotation/position.
      CCMoveTo* moveTo = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:.25 position:point];
      CCRotateTo* rotateTo = [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:.25 angle:angle];

      [self.tile runAction:moveTo];
      [self.tile runAction:rotateTo];
}
```